# protobuf-net - Why after Deserializing object that reference to same object are not equal

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, protobuf-net

The above question is very vague so let me elaborate.

In my code I have it set up something like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(50, typeof(SubGroup))]
public class BaseGroup
{
    [ProtMember(1)]
    List<BaseElement> elements;
}
[ProtoContract]
public class SubGroup : BaseGroup
{
    //Some protomembers
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(Set))]
public class BaseElement
{
    [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true)]
    BaseGroup Parent;
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Set : BaseElement
{
    //some protomembers here
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    List<Band> bands;
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Band
{
    //some protomembers here
    [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true)]
    Set Parent;
}
```

Now, somewhere in another part of my code I perform something like this:

```
public void Function(Band b)
{
    Set parentSet = b.Parent;
    SubGroup parentGroup = (SubGroup)parentSet.Parent;
    foreach(Set s in parentGroup.elements)
    {
        if(!s.Equals(parentSet))
        {
            //This section of code is skipped when references s and parentSet are equal.
            //I then save to file by serializing the entire Basegroup, I 
            //then deserialize back into a BaseGroup object.
            //Once deserialized, this function is called and this part of the code 
            //is executed meaning the objects with supposedly the same reference 
            //are not equal anymore.
            //I performed this test with only one Set object meaning only one object in 
            //in the List of elements in the BaseGroup object
        }
    } 
}
```

I hope I explained this correctly.  I have only been doing C# for about a year.

Comment: Have you implemented `Equals` or are you just using the one declared in `object` that does reference equality check? (meaning that only the same original reference will equal itself)

Comment: Yes, I am using the implementation found in `Object`.  I seemed to have found the problem supported by @user270576's answer.

Comment: BTW is this data structure a representation of the periodic table?

Comment: No, it's a representation of bands within spectral sets that is used for spectroscopy analysis.

Comment: @BenVoigt The keywords I used were just to keep the example more general.  Not in reference to periodic elements.

Answer (score 2):

Serialization/deserialization does not preserve object references. Thus, after deserialization every object is new.

Comment: This is a limitation of protobuf serialization, right?  I know that other serialization frameworks go to considerable effort to reconstruct links within object graphs.

Comment: No, it is a limitation of your knowledge. The *whole purpose* of serialization and deserialization (notice that I did not limit this to *protobuf*) is to create a representation of an object graph fit for transport, and then to take that representation and give you new objects from it. Serialization/deserialization will "never" give you back the original object, it will "always" give you new objects. If you then do a reference comparison between the original objects, and the serialized->deserialized objects, you will "always" get a mismatch.

Comment: I say "always" and "never" in quotes because obviously you can create a system where you store references to existing objects and create a deserialization system that will attempt to match data to an existing object instead of creating a new one. This, however, is a **very special case**!

Comment: @BenVoigt: The way I read it, author tries to compare original object *b.Parent* to an object inside newly-deserialized *parentGroup*. In this case object references will be different regardless of serialization framework. (@lasse was correct in his interpretation of my words).
BTW, protobuf declares graph support as "optional". In my experience that means "not available".
BTW2, the code has way to many .Parent.Parent relations and needless types (SubGroup could be safely omitted), which makes it hard to understand.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Question is, is a facsimile created of the entire graph, or is a facsimile created of each object encountered while walking the graph?  If I have one `List<T>` and one object `new T()` and add it to the list 5 times, after transport through serialization will I get one copy of the object and five references to it, or five copies of the object?  Of course one does not expect `afterList[1] == beforeList[1]`.  But one does expect `afterList[1] == afterList[0]` iff `beforeList[1] == beforeList[0]`.

Comment: The answer to *that* question depends on the serialization/deserialization technology. With protobuf, or json, or xml, by default you will get 5 copies. With binary serialization ([BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx)) you will get 5 references to the same object.

Comment: Yeah, graph support doesn't seem to work. Also, @user270576 I am comparing the objects like that.  From my answer that I supported, I worked around this by going through each object within a list and assign the Parents from the created classes Post-Deserialization.  That way the references are all concurrent.  Works great.

Comment: @Lasse: And that's what my first comment was getting at.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I didn't quite fully understand why I was getting the results I got.  I did however discover a method in working around this problem.  I decided to remove the `[Protomember(n,AsReference = true)]` attribute from all the parent references. I then constructed a function with the `[ProtoAfterDeserializationAttribute]`attribute that will go through each object and assign each Parent reference using `this` keyword.  This will ensure the objects are of equal reference.

Comment: To my understanding, I assumed this is why the `AsReference` attribute is used in order to specify the object is a reference, not seperate object.

Answer (score 0):

I realise thread is old now but the follow code works for me. AsReference = true indicates its stored as a reference and as you can see below each "Parent" object is stored as a single object, rather than new instances. See the debugger watch window.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Parent
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<Child> Children
    {
        get { return m_Children; }
        set { m_Children = value; }
    }

    private List<Child> m_Children = new List<Child>();
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Child
{
    [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true)]
    public Parent Parent
    {
        get { return m_Parent; }
        set { m_Parent = value; }
    }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Index
    {
        get { return m_Index; }
        set { m_Index = value; }
    }

    Parent m_Parent;
    int m_Index;
}
```

//Test Code

```
            Parent p = new Parent();
        p.Children.Add(new Child()
        {
            Parent = p,
            Index = 0
        });
        p.Children.Add(new Child()
        {
            Parent = p,
            Index = 1
        });

        using (var file = File.Create("graph.bin"))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(file, p);
        }

        Parent newPerson;
        using (var file = File.OpenRead("graph.bin"))
        {
            newPerson = Serializer.Deserialize<Parent>(file);
        }
```

[image]